# Orden de datos de una consulta en php

Tags: php, mysql, array

Resulta que tengo una tabla con varios datos de solicitudes y deseo ordenarlos desde el último recibido.

Mi consulta es la siguiente:

```
$pqr = "SELECT * FROM pqr WHERE cliente = $id AND estado != 3 ORDER BY 'interno' DESC";
$resultado = mysqli_query($db, $pqr);
```

...En la tabla lo muestro asi:

```
...<tbody><?php while ($consultaPqr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) : ?>
       <tr>
           <td>NS-23-<?php echo $consultaPqr['interno']; ?></td>...
```

Pero al mostrarlo en la página se muestra así...
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
No he podido hacer que se ordene correctamente, siempre me envía los de un solo dígito al final.

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: El orden que te está dando es correcto, porque ahí el `3` es un `30` con respecto al `24`. Si quieres garantizar un orden, debes rellenar con `0`, o bien redefinir tu modelo de datos. Yo haría esto último,  porque esto, más que un error circunstancial, podría ser **un error de diseño**. Esos errores se pagan caros, como cuando un edificio tiene vicios de construcción, el mismo puede aguantar un año o 50 años, pero termina derrumbándose tarde o temprano.

Comment: Hola Ivan, ¿la tabla tiene un campo auto-increment o un datetime donde guardes la fecha y hora del creación del registro? Al ser una cadena de texto el orden que realiza es alfabetico

Comment: Hola @Marcos...  el id es autoincremental.. el valor "NS-23-" lo coloque en la tabla no viene de la DB... solo viene el numero del id.

Comment: @A.Cedano el campo id que da origen al orden es tipo INT... como puedo definir el modelo de datos para evitar el error.

Comment: Si ese ID que refieres ya sirve como orden, entonces ordena los resultados por ese ID en la consulta SQL y listo. En ese caso, no hace falta redifinir el modelo de datos. Yo, al ver la captura, pensé que tenías un campo alfanumérico al estilo `NS-99-9` con el cual pretendías hacer el orden. Convendría qué expliques qué es lo que define el orden de esas filas, si es sólo ese ID y si eso basta, o si deben intervenir otras columnas, como la fecha. En la consulta ordenas por una columna `interno` sin explicar lo que es esa columna.

Comment: @A.Cedano...  "interno" es el numero que acompaña al "NS-23-interno" y es un número autoincremental...  sin embargo he ordenado por id y por interno... pero por ninguna funciona

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar un pequeño set de datos de tu tabla, y la definición de la misma? Ejecutando un `SHOW CREATE TABLE cliente` la puedes obtener.

Comment: `interno` es un VARCHAR, no un `INT`, debes ordenar por la columna `id`. No uses el área de respuestas para añadir contenido aclaratorio. Y el `CREATE TABLE` es mejor ponerlo como texto.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `pqr` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
...
  `interno` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cliente` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
...

Comment: Ahora surge otro problema, al crear una nueva PQR se debe incrementar en +1 el último valor de la tabla... está identificando 9 como último valor... entonces me genera la PQR 10, debería ser la PQR25

Comment: @ivanjaviergonzalezabello disculpa la demora en responder. Por favor, la proxima vez utiliza la opción [edit] y agrega la definición de la tabla en la pregunta. Los comentarios son temporales. Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Una solución a tu problema es que, por ejemplo, al momento de ordenar conviertas el campo `interno` que es un `varchar(25)` a `unsigned`

#### Ejemplo:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM pqr 
WHERE cliente = $id AND estado != 3 
ORDER BY CAST(interno AS UNSIGNED) DESC
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/e7VeDBtfBwLksPc8rjKmj/0)

---

Otra opción es que lo hagas al seleccionar las columnas a recuperar.

#### Ejemplo:

```sql
SELECT 
  CAST(interno AS UNSIGNED) AS interno,
  cliente,
  estado,
  ... 
FROM pqr 
WHERE cliente = $id AND estado != 3 
ORDER BY interno DESC
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/e7VeDBtfBwLksPc8rjKmj/1)

Comment: muchas gracias por la respuesta... efectivamente estaba tratando en campo como int y esto impedia el orden...  Gracias

Comment: @ivanjaviergonzalezabello, si la respuesta te ayudo a resolver tu problema, considera votarla y/o marcarla como aceptada. Más info: [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)